# EF6: Custom Proxy, good or bad idea?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

this issue arose for me when I had events which call multiple event handlers, but pass each one the same entity. Now, because entities are bound to one context in EF, passing the context along to the event handlers violated the one context per unit of work principle.

So the best I could come up with is a kind of factory and custom proxy (in this example only for `Player`, but I have more EF entities like `Human`, `Participation`, etc):

```
public class PlayerProxy : Player {
    protected SnowbiteContext Context;
    protected Player RealPlayer;
    private long? _playerId;
    private string _name;

    public static Func<SnowbiteContext, PlayerProxy> NewProxyFactory(string name) =>
        (ctx) => new PlayerProxy(ctx) {Name = name};

    public static Func<SnowbiteContext, PlayerProxy> NewProxyFactory(long playerId) =>
        (ctx) => new PlayerProxy(ctx) {PlayerId = playerId};

    public PlayerProxy(SnowbiteContext ctx) {
        Context = ctx ?? throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    public void Populate() {
        if (RealPlayer != null) return;
        if (_playerId != null) RealPlayer = Context.Players.Single(p => p.PlayerId == _playerId);
        if (_name != null)
            RealPlayer =
                Context.Players.SingleOrDefault(p =>
                    p.Name == _name) ?? /* Contact external json API, complicated and expensive */;
    }

    public override long PlayerId {
        get {
            if (_playerId == null) Populate();
            Debug.Assert(_playerId != null, nameof(_playerId) + " != null");
            return _playerId.Value;
        }
        set {
            Populate();
            RealPlayer.PlayerId = value;
            _playerId = null;
        }
    }

    public override string Name {
        get {
            if (_name == null) Populate();
            return _name;
        }
        set {
            Populate();
            RealPlayer.Name = value;
            _name = null;
        }
    }

    public override Human Human {
        get {
            Populate();
            return RealPlayer.Human;
        }
        set {
            Populate();
            RealPlayer.Human = value;
        }
    }

    public override long HumanId {
        get {
            Populate();
            return RealPlayer.HumanId;
        }
        set {
            Populate();
            RealPlayer.HumanId = value;
        }
    }

    public override ICollection<Participation> Participations {
        get {
            Populate();
            return RealPlayer.Participations;
        }
        set {
            Populate();
            RealPlayer.Participations = value;
        }
    }

    // Etc... for EaGuid, Tag, Rank.
}
```

Then the events would go like:

```
    private void RCON_event_OnChat(IReadOnlyList<string> words) {
        var name = words[1];
        if (name == "Server") return;

        EvChat?.Invoke(PlayerProxy.NewProxyFactory(name), words[2]);
    }
```

And the event handlers (Player N:1 Human):

```
void Handler(Func<SnowbiteContext, PlayerProxy> playerProxyFactory, string message) {
    using (var ctx = new SnowbiteContext()) {
        PlayerProxy playerProxy = playerProxyFactory(ctx);
        // use stuff, unit of work being done here, etc.

        // but how about relating my proxy to other entities? Will EF handle my derived type correctly?
        Human humanFromER = ctx.Humans.Single(/* ... */);
        humanFromER.Players.Add(playerProxy);
        playerProxy.Human = humanFromER;

        // how about 1:N with ICollection<Participation>? Will EF recognize it properly?
        playerProxy.Participations.Add(/* some new participation */);
    }
}
```

For reference, here's my `Player` Entity:

```
public class Player {
    public Player() {
        Participations = new List<Participation>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     BalzeId / PersonaId
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public virtual long PlayerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual long HumanId { get; set; }

    public virtual Human Human { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Not a key. Mostly provided for convenicencet.
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(35)]
    public virtual string EaGuid { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4)]
    public virtual string Tag { get; set; }

    public virtual int Rank { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Participation> Participations { get; set; }
}
```

Or maybe just passing a `string name` to the event handler and having a simple function to get a player from the DB would have been simpler :D.

**Update**

Based on Gert Arnold's comment, I came up with this, getting rid of the proxy entirely:

```
private void RCON_event_OnChat(IReadOnlyList<string> words) {
    var name = words[1];
    if (name == "Server") return;
    if (EvChat != null) {
        // additionally, will be easy to convert to async
        foreach (var handler in EvChat.GetInvocationList().Cast<Action<SnowbiteContext, Player, string>>()) {
            using (var ctx = new SnowbiteContext()) {
                var player = ctx.Players.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == name) ?? /* expensive resolve */;
                handler(ctx, player, words[2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of proxies. How bad would it hurt you to disable proxy and manually include / load the things you need?

Comment: @grek40 I could pass a `string name` instead of this overly complicated proxy factory thing, and then in the event handlers call a function like `var player = GetOrResolvePlayer(ctx, name);` and have an overload for the player id version.

I just thought it wasn't very OOP-y.

Comment: I have a gut feeling that these event handlers are far too complex. The complexity seems to arise from a disputable architectural decision to have a UoW per handler. I think the handlers should only *signal* changes to be made to one object graph and a higher level UoW should save them.

Comment: @GertArnold That's a very good idea :D See the update, is this what you imagined?

Comment: Now that I think about it, that way there'll be multiple identical queries sent to the database (amount of event listeners),.. that's not good.

Comment: But that makes me wonder what this new context is doing in there. You seem to have a UoW and a UoW should contain one context. Maybe your event handlers should receive a `Player` object?

Comment: @GertArnold `RCON_event_OnChat` is a function which gets called by the layer that handles the socket to the game server. It's supposed to call the event listeners that subscribed for the EvChat event, and there can be multiple. If I want to pass only `Player`, the handlers won't be able to do some of their work, and they might need to add or change a relationship, add/remove an Entity, etc. So a UoW here would be the work happening inside the event handler. Did I understand UoW wrong? Did I understand your question wrong?